# How to store e.latlng into array : leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

I am working with leaflet api where user can put markers on map. I have made a custom button for putting marker.

I am willing to draw line between those markers i.e. using
`L.polylines()` but as I am new to javascript and leaflet I can't
understand how to pass those latlng point to array which will later be
used in these functions. For initial working I have passed static
coordinates(working as req).

```
L.easyButton('fa-link', function () {

var secureThisArea = [[-81, 100.75], [-76.50, 245.75], [-145.50, 184.25], [-128, 311.75]];

    map.on('click', function fencePlace(e) {

    L.marker([-81, 100.75], { icon: fenceIcon, draggable: true }).bindPopup("this is first").addTo(map);
    L.marker([-76.50, 245.75], { icon: fenceIcon, draggable: true }).bindPopup("this is second").addTo(map);
    L.marker([-145.50, 184.25], { icon: fenceIcon, draggable: true }).bindPopup("this is third").addTo(map);
    L.marker([-128, 311.75], { icon: fenceIcon, draggable: true }).bindPopup("this is fourth").addTo(map);
    L.polyline(secureThisArea).addTo(map);

});
                }).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Please stop using `....` and `,,,,` - these are not real forms of punctuation, they are noise with no semantic meaning.

Comment: @meagar ok sir...i won't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding another value to an array is easy, e.g.:

```
secureThisArea.push([-81, 100.75]);
```

You can find more details (also about anything else JavaScript related) at [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray).

If you want to use the coordinates from the marker objects, you can get those with:

```
var myMarker = L.marker([-81, 100.75], { icon: fenceIcon, draggable: true }),
    latLng = null;

latLng = myMarker.getLatLng();
```

Also take a look at the [Leaflet documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html).

Comment: thanks for answer, +1 for help and i will surely accept answer

Answer (score 2):

If i understand you correctly you want to create markers on click and connect them via polylines. That's easy to do, in code with comments to explain:

```
// Create new empty polyline and add it to the map
var polyline = new L.Polyline([]).addTo(map);

// Handle map click event
map.on('click', function(event) {

    // New marker on coordinate, add it to the map
    new L.Marker(event.latlng).addTo(map);

    // Add coordinate to the polyline
    polyline.addLatLng(event.latlng);

});
```

Now afterwards if you want to get all the coordinates added to the polyline you can use the `getLatLngs` method of `L.Polyline` which returns an array of `L.LatLng` objects.

Reference: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#polyline

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/h7aMwc?p=preview

Comment: thanks for answer, its the perfect solution for my understanding, i wish i can give more than upvote,,,,

Comment: No thanks, always welcome. If it's a better answer to your question than the one you've accepted you can always accept another instead. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer